# iPhoneOS Core Data migration: moving something from an entity into a file

Tags: iphone, core-data, migration, mapping-model

I have a scenario where I'm moving the contents of a blob stored in a core data entity into a file. I need a way to export that data during a migration, where I know the entity that's being converted and save the blob to a file, writing the location of that file into the converted entity's appropriate attribute.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. The [docs regarding the Three Stage Migration](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005508-SW8) seem to indicate what can be done, but I'm not sure where to define things, or what exactly to define.

Comment: The place to ask about unreleased apple software specifically as it relates to programming while it is still under NDA is the apple dev forums. Once iOS is released to users, then we can talk about it on SO, but I know myself, while it would be nice to answer this, I can't right now due to the apple confidential material clauses of the SDK agreement.

Comment: This isn't unreleased. I'm talking about v3.2, but the concepts are common to all recent versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a mapping model and then creating a custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` for that entity.  From there you can do the modifications to your data structure as needed.